# Can there be an entire function such that $f(\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2n},$ and $f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{9}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\begin{align}
f(\frac{1}{2n})=\frac{1}{2n},
\text{ and } 
f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{9}
\end{align}
$$
 Prove that there can't be an entire function $f$ such that the upper conditions are fulfilled.

I am trying to prove this, but I don't know how. Any hint, advice or guidance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: let  $n$ integer and $n>0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If entire functions are equal on a sequence of points which accumulates, they must be equal everywhere.  Since $\{\frac{1}{2n}\}$ accumulates at 0, the first condition implies $f(z) \equiv z$, which contradicts the second.

Comment: I get that this comes from the Identity theorem, but was it that simple? ( sorry for my english, and many thanks for quick response )

Comment: Yes, I believe it is.

Comment: would the same thinking aplly in a case with a holomorphic function $f:D(0,1)\to\mathbb{C}$ to prove something similar?

Comment: Yes, it still works as long $\{1/(2n)\}$ accumulates inside the domain--in other words, as long as zero is in the domain.  In particular, it works for the disk.